# How to get a class instance of Parameterized type with two generics

Tags: java, generics

I have:

```
public class RestClientResource<T,U> {
}
```

and want to determine the class of U.

I have this:

```
Class<U> uClass = 
(Class<U>) ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

but it doesnt't work, presumably because I have multiple generic parameterized types

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Where is `U` specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it doesnt't work, presumably because I have multiple generic parameterized type

This shouldn't be an issue.

There are a couple of things that jump out:

1. You need there to actually be a generic superclass:

   > ```
   > getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
   > ```

   Make your class `abstract`, in order that it *has* to be subclassed:

   ```
   public abstract class RestClientResource<T,U> {
   ```
2. If you want the `U` class, access the `[1]`th element of the array:

   ```
   ....getActualTypeArguments()[1]
   ```

   Otherwise you get the `T`.

Comment: Ahh thanks - you've revealed my lack of understanding of generics. This now makes complete sense, and works.